# Formal derivative of polynomials with coefficients in a quotient ring $GF(2)[x]/p(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives, finite-fields, polynomial-rings

How do you determine the formal derivative of polynomials with coefficients in a quotient ring $GF(2)[x]/p(x)$?

I am comfortable with calculating formal derivatives of polynomials with coefficients in a prime finite field, for example if $f(x) = 3x^4 + 6x^2$ in $GF(7)[x]$ then $f'(x) = 12x^3 + 12x = 5x^3 + 5x$.

But I'm confused what to do with, for example, $f(y) = ay^4 + by^2$ where, for example, $a = x^2 + 1$ and $b = x^2 + x$ in some finite field isomorphic to $GF(2^3)$. Presumably it has something to do with $f'(y) = 4ay^3 + 2by$... but do I take $4 \bmod 2$ and $2 \bmod 2$ to determine $f'(y) = 0$? Or do I work in $\bmod 8$? Or is this not defined?

Comment: $4a=0$ as an element of $\mathbf{F}_8$ where is the problem ?  Try with $\mathbf{F}_4 = \mathbf{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$. Then $D(\sum_{n=0}^N a_n y^n) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n n y^{n-1}$ is a $\mathbf{F}_4$-linear map $\mathbf{F}_4[y] \to \mathbf{F}_4[y]$. The kernel of $D$ is $\mathbf{F}_4[y^2]$.

Comment: If $f(y) = ay^4 + by^2$ where $a,b \in GF(8)$ (i.e., $a$ and $b$ are constants) then yes, $f'(y) = 4ay^3 + 2by$. Now $GF(8)$ has characteristic $2$. So for *any* $c \in GF(8)$, $2c=0$. In particular $4a=2b=0$. So $f'(y) = 0$ (identically, i.e., equality in the polynomial ring, not just equality as functions or equal values at a particular input or anything like that). It didn't really matter what $a$ and $b$ were.

Comment: ok so the characteristic is the determining factor here. could you add an answer? if so I'll accept.